# How to reduce table of objects and calculate the sum of similar values?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a function in angular and I want to reduce a list of objects like this example  :

```
var tab =[{name:'i', value:13}, {name:'j', value:10},{name:'i', value:8}]
```

I want to get this result :

```
tab = [{name:'i', value:21},{name:'j', value:10}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the array contains an object with the same `name` property with [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and if so, increment the `value` property. Otherwise, push to the array.

```js
var tab = [{name: 'i', value: 13}, {name: 'j', value: 10}, {name: 'i', value: 8}]
const result = tab.reduce((a, b) => {
  let found = a.find(e => e.name == b.name);
  return found ? found.value += b.value : a.push(b), a
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just chopping off the last element within an array you should be able to just use the reduceRight() function. [Click here for more on the reduce Method](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-reduce/#:%7E:text=%20JavaScript%20Array%20reduce%20%26%20reduceRight%3A%20Reducing%20an,%28%29%20examples.%20Notice%20that%20in%20this...%20More%20)

```js
let tab =[{name:'i', value:13}, {name:'j', value:10},{name:'k', value:8}]

tab.reduceRight();

console.log(tab);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Spectric is a default solution for this problem and would be preferred in most cases as it is clear and straightforward. However I asked myself if we can solve it without additional iteration (via `find` function) and came up with following solution.

```js
var tab = [{ name: 'i', value: 13 }, { name: 'j', value: 10 }, { name: 'i', value: 8 }, { name: 'j', value: 8 }];
const result = tab.reduce((a, b, i) => {
    let found = a.tmp.hasOwnProperty(b.name);
    return !found ? a.res[a.tmp[b.name] = i] = b : a.res[a.tmp[b.name]].value += b.value, a;
}, { tmp: {}, res: [] }).res;

console.log(result);
```

It is adding auxiliary tmp object saving index of a given unique element in the result array and allows us to do everything in one iteration. I could imagine this to be better in terms of performance if we had a lot of objects of only few distinct types.